# Cannot see the number on the left hand of an object side in console log

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, javascript-objects

The problem I'm trying to solve is creating a dynamic object initiallizer im pretty sure it's called. Instead of hardcoding in a number in the object since I don't know the outcome of the number. A code example will demonstrate the example.

Ive tried to create a simple for loop to interate through a number to display in the console later on but nothing successful so far.

```
 for(var counter =0; counter <3; counter++){
    var myObject = {counter : "Text"};
    console.log(myObject)
 }
```

But the output shows the actual variable name instead of the number it contains. The output needs to be exactly like this example: {0:"Example"}.

Output in the console window in Chrome: 
{counter: "Text"} {counter: "Text"} {counter: "Text"}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use the bracket notation `[]` to use variables as keys(dynamic keys) in objects

```js
for (var counter = 0; counter < 3; counter++) {
  var myObject = {
    [counter]: "Text"
  };
  console.log(myObject)
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you very much